# Application/octet-stream is set as mediaType when uploading json file payload using form parameters instead of application/json

Tags: json, jersey, mime-types, multipart, form-parameter

I am using jersey implementation for creating a REST service and trying to upload .json file to the server using form parameters.
I am creating a FileDataBodyPart object and passing it to object of FormDataMultiPart.

FileDataBodyPart fileBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart(name, file);
form.bodyPart(fileBodyPart);

The default MediaType that is getting set here is application/octet-stream. I looked at jersey library code, it internally "decides" which mediatype to set. If the file type is not in the list of CommonMediaTypes then it sets it as octect-stream.

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/21b7cc0307d6432eb301f773d5c2c674425c6b10/media/multipart/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/file/DefaultMediaTypePredictor.java#L136

The above URL points to the jersey code which lists available mediatypes.
application/json is not in the list of supported formats.

I wanted to know if there is a specific reason for not supporting the json format by jersey library? Or
The support for application/json is added in more recent versions of jersey for multipart file upload.

Comment: [You have the option to set the media type](http://javadox.com/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles/apidocs/2.11/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/file/FileDataBodyPart.html#FileDataBodyPart(java.lang.String,%20java.io.File,%20javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PaulSamsotha. Yes, I am able to set the mediaType to application/json.
Wanted to know any specific reason it was not added in the common mediatype list?

Comment: Probably because JSON generally is not sent as _files_.